# How to format array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

I am trying to read in files that contain sales data (name, location and amount). Each file is for a different person but can contain multiple entries. When I read them from disk, I get something like this:

Step 1:

```
    Array (
        [0] => sue
        [1] => salem
        [2] => 30
    )

    Array (
        [0] => bob
        [1] => salem
        [2] => 10
    )

    Array (
        [0] => sue
        [1] => benton
        [2] => 2
    )

    Array (
        [0] => bob
        [1] => benton
        [2] => 30
    )
```

Step 2: I need to convert the above to this array:

```
    Array (
        [0] => array (
                [name] => sue
                [locn] => salem
                [sales] => 30
                ) 
        [1] => array (
                [name] => bob
                [locn] => salem
                [sales] => 10
                )
        [2] => array (
                [name] => sue
                [locn] => benton
                [sales] => 2
                )    
        [3] => array (
                [name] => bob
                [locn] => benton
                [sales] => 30
                )
    )
```

Then I would walk that array like this:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sales_array); $i += 2) { 
      echo 'LOCN: ' . $sales_array[$i]['locn'];
      echo ' NAME: ' . $sales_array[$i]['name'] . ' - ' . $sales_array[$i]['sales'];
      echo ' NAME: ' . $sales_array[$i+1]['name'] . ' - ' . $sales_array[$i+1]['sales'];
    }
```

The idea is to get this result:

```
    LOCN: salem   NAME: Sue - 30  NAME: Bob - 10
    LOCN: benton  NAME: Sue - 3   NAME: Bob - 30
```

There are two problems, at least. The first problem is in going from Step 1 to Step 2. I can't figure out how to get the array I need.

The second problem is that the code assumes the first two items will be for the same location. They are in my tests due to how I read in the files but I'm not sure that will always be the case. Would someone show me a how to do that or a better way to accomplish this, please?

Comment: I have edited my answer in case my answer did not help you enough

Comment: Does each person get their own column? What if there are 50 sales people. Will there be only 1 person named Sue?

Comment: Is none of the answers correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_combine to make the arrays associative.

```
$keys = ["name", "locn", "sales"];
Foreach($arr as &$subarr){
    $subarr = array_combine($keys, $subarr);
}
```

This loops through your array and combines keys and the subarray with the values.
The original array should be as your "step2".

https://3v4l.org/MuKvo

---

To get the second part for you I would not use the array setup as you want.
I would use the associative to keep the locations grouped in each array.

```
$keys = ["name", "locn", "sales"];
Foreach($arr as $subarr){
    $res[$subarr[1]][] = array_combine($keys, $subarr);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/hoOhC
Output example

```
$res[salem][0][name] = "sue"
```

This will make a slightly different array structure but it will keep your cities in one array each making it easy to get the result you want in your echo part.

In case you need with the output of the above array, here is one example:
https://3v4l.org/Y6OKk

```
$prev_city ="";
foreach($res as $city => $sales_array){
    echo 'LOCN: ' . $city . " <br>\n";
    foreach($sales_array as $sales){
        echo ' NAME: ' . $sales['name'] . ' - ' . $sales['sales'] . " <br>\n";
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
}
```

This will output:

```
LOCN: salem 
 NAME: sue - 30 
 NAME: bob - 10 

LOCN: benton 
 NAME: sue - 2 
 NAME: bob - 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys positions are fixed, you could use below method

```
  $sales_array = array();
  foreach($step1 As $array){
  //construct the inner array     
  $person = array("name"=>$array[0],'locn'=>$array[1],'sales'=>$array[3]);
  // add it to sales_array
  $sales_array []= $person;
  }
```

Then iterate through the data as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data like this:

```
$x = array_reduce($input, function($carry, $item) {
    $keys = ['name', 'locn', 'sales'];
    $carry[] = array_combine($keys, $item);
    return $carry;
}, []);

print_r($x);
```

If the data will be in any order then you need to organize it so that you can get what you want. I am making some assumptions because you haven't make some things clear.

1. It looks like you need data organized by location
2. the person's name is unique.
3. A person can be in more than one location.
4. For each location, a person will only be in the data once.

xxxxx

```
$input = [
  ['Thorn', 'East', 10],
  ['Sue', 'West', 20],
  ['Sue', 'North', 30],
  ['Fenton', 'North', 12],  
  ['Sue', 'South', 40],    
  ['Bob', 'South', 17], 
  ['Marc', 'East', 11],
  ['Sam', 'West', 20],
  ['Adam', 'South', 19], 
];

$masterData = array_reduce($input, function($carry, $row) {
    $carry[$row[1]][$row[0]] = $row[2];
    return $carry;
}, []);

//print_r($masterData);
foreach($masterData as $location => $salesArr) {
    echo $location . "\n";
    $names = array_keys($salesArr);
    sort($names);
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo '  ' . $name . '  ' . $salesArr[$name] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
East
  Marc  11
  Thorn  10
West
  Sam  20
  Sue  20
North
  Fenton  12
  Sue  30
South
  Adam  19
  Bob  17
  Sue  40
```

You can format the data any way you need from this point.